# php how to list with sub heading

Tags: php, html, mysql

New to php environment, what I am trying to do is create a list using php and MySQL database. see below

-----my output requirements info ------

main page heading

subheading1 (content of brandtype=1)

1111

2222

3333

4444 ( I want these as a hyperlink to open in the same webpage)

subheading2 (brandtype=2)

5555

6666

7777

8888 ( I want these as a hyperlink to open in the same webpage)

my code below

// Connect to database server

```
include 'xxxxxyyyyzzzz.php';
$conn = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password);
mysql_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password) or die (mysql_error ());

mysql_select_db($db_database,$conn) or die(mysql_error()); // Select database
echo "<h1>main webpage heading</h1>"; 
echo "<h3>my subheading</h3>"; 
// SQL query

$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table name WHERE brand type='1','Software'  ORDER BY serviceName ASC";

// Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)

$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

// Loop the recordset $rs

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

$strName = $row['serviceName'];
$strLink = "<a href = 'person.php?id = " . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $strName . "</a>";

// List link

echo "<li>" . $strLink . "</li>";

//  include 'emaild.php';  
 }

// Close the database connection

mysql_close();
?>

</ul>
 </body>
 </html>
  end of my code
```

I am getting a listing ok, but have to put in subheading manually (e.g. echo "

## main title page names

"; echo "

#### subheading title

";  depending on the brand type ?

- how can tweak my code so that where my brand type = 1 it prints a heading brand type1 and then prints out the items for that brand 1 underneath it, if there are no items , then it does not print subheading (brand type=1) and goes to the next to print subheading for brandtype=2 and lists the content underneath it.
- I can make list items underneath each subheading as links to a webpage but it does not work, how can I make these list items open on the same webpage with more details of product and I would use back button to go previous list webpage...thanks in advance..singhy

Comment: a) Use mysqli_xx instead of mysql_xx functions.
b) <li> is supposed to be in <ol> or <ul>.
c) multi-level lists are in HTML created by puting a new list into <li>, e.g. <ul><li>item<ul><li>inner item</li></ul></li></ul>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the brand names in a different table where it can be read? If it's not you can do it manually still, but will much more ease (See below). If so, please let us know where that is located.

```
SendBrandListings(1, "Brand 1 Header");
SendBrandListings(2, "Brand 2 Header");


function SendBrandListings($brandId, $heading){
    echo "<h3>$heading</h3>"; 
    $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM table name WHERE brand type='$brandId','Software'  ORDER BY serviceName ASC";
    $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
        $strName = $row['serviceName'];
        $strLink = "<a href = 'person.php?id = " . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $strName . "</a>";
        echo "<li>" . $strLink . "</li>";
    }
}
```

---

### ***UPDATE***

If your brand name is in the same table, let's say the field is `brandName` - you would modify you current loop to this (simplified for demo purposes).

First, you'll want to ensure that your results are sorted by Brand FIRST, then by service name. This is because we will be looping through the services in the order they are received in. This will arrange items of a like brand together. So make sure your SQL statement's sorting argument looks like this:

`ORDER BY brandName, serviceName ASC`

Simply keep track of the last Brand Name you displayed, and if it changes, display the new one.

```
$c = 0; //Variable to keep count of categories
$lastBrand = '';    //Declare a variable to track the last displayed Brand Name    
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

    //If the brand name has changed, display it and update the tracking variable
    if ($lastBrand != $row['brandName']){
        $lastBrand = $row['brandName'];

        //If this isn't the first category, end the previous list.
        if ($c>0) echo "</ul>";

        echo '<h3>'.$row['brandName'].'</h3><ul>';
        $c++;
    }

    $strName = $row['serviceName'];
    $strLink = "<a href = 'person.php?id = " . $row['ID'] . "'>" . $strName . "</a>";


    echo "<li>" . $strLink . "</li>";
}
```

Comment: Hi dutchie432 thanks for the quick response, yes the brand name is in the same table, I wanted to do it dynamically rather than manually as if certain brand type does not exist then I don't need to print subheading for it...save time. how can I test the code you sent me,i want a somesort of a loop so that if one brand type does not exist then it goes to the next one until brand type name is finished, is this possible..? thanks again...singhy

Comment: Hi dutchie432 thanks for this I will tweak my code accordingly and get back how I get on thanks...singhy

Comment: You got it. Note: The code has been updated to enclose the lists in the proper `<ul>...</ul>`. Note #2: I did not TEST this code, so there could be a little mistake here or there.

Comment: hi there dutchie432 could not open last message, and could not post the code snippet, thanks, I am still working on it...what I managed to do is kind of trying to find other easier way to basically split the list I am getting from database and then putting in subheadings of output depending upon the brandtype !,I can manage to get all the content in ascending order and then I am trying to put in brand type heading within the list !, thanks singhy

Comment: hi dutchie thanks for your help, managed to get it working but having two problems,the first brand type subheading does not appear and not in ascending order, the rest are ok. I am unable to to get the list hyperlink to open in same webpage (person.php) code below $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM <tablename> WHERE id = " . $_GET["id"];
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);echo "<dt>ID:</dt><dd>" . $row["ID"] . " " . $row["guUrl"] . "</dd>";
echo "<dt>availability:</dt><dd>" . $row["availability"] . "</dd>";}  this button returns to previous list webpage..this webpage gives more details of two fields...thanks

Comment: hi there dutchie just figured out that from my last message the first piece of content with no subheading is correct as it has printed that do not have any brand type, how can I tweak the code so it does not print anything that does not belong to brandtype ?, thanks again, still working the other link problem, thanks singhy

Comment: hi dutchie432 thanks but still having problems with trying to get the links to open in the samewebpage and trying to get the more detailed  webpage to open (detail.php), I have posted the code on a separate question as I can not post the whole code in the comments box...thanks..singhy

Comment: Those topic really belong in another question. If I've helped you, please accept the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Dutchie432 thanks again for all your help, I am still trying to solve the other detailed webpage , tryiong to get output from a id from previous webpage...thanks...singhy

Comment: You asked how to generate a list with headings. That's what this thread is about. If I've helped you get that done, please accept this answer. If you have further questions about other tasks, ask them in another thread. That's how this site works.

Comment: hi there dutchie sorry new here, yes ive already done that few days back !, thanks again singhy